# How to 2-finger touch on the "google_maps_flutter" to only zoom, but keep the center of the screen fixed

Tags: flutter, google-maps, multi-touch, google-maps-flutter

I'm building a mobile map app with Flutter, and I want to zoom with two-finger taps, but I don't want the screen to slide.

I want to completely separate the functions, with one-finger touch to move the center of the screen and two-finger touch to zoom.

Additionally, I would like to know how to limit the zoom units to only integers.
I can think of two ways to do this, one where the zoom goes from 6 to 6.1 and when you release the touch it goes to 7.
The other way is to change the zoom to an unconditional rounded value.
Either way, I'd like to make it simple to implement.

[my current code]

```
GoogleMap(
  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
    target: center,
    zoom: zoom.toDouble(),
  ),
  onMapCreated: mapController.complete,
  mapToolbarEnabled: false,
  cameraTargetBounds: CameraTargetBounds(LatLngBounds(
    southwest: const LatLng(33, 124),
    northeast: const LatLng(39, 132),
  )),
  minMaxZoomPreference: const MinMaxZoomPreference(6, 18),
  rotateGesturesEnabled: false,
  zoomControlsEnabled: false,
  tiltGesturesEnabled: false,
  myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
)
```

Comment: Hello! Can you show us what you have tried so far? Providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your current progress and issue will be a good start.

Comment: Thanks for the help!!!
https://youtube.com/shorts/UUGHrCwU9Pw
https://youtube.com/shorts/tUiwWk1w-3o
The first video is an app called Naver Real Estate that I used as a reference.
The second video is a map I made with Flutter's Google Maps.
In Flutter, the center wobbles when zooming with multi-touch.
Let me know if you need more details.